# Laravel Yajra Datatables raw SQL

Tags: laravel, datatable, yajra-datatable

Using Yajra Datables, Laravel is returning "Memory exhausted..." error message.
Actually how do we applying the filtering & sorting directly to the SQL instead of letting the server-side handle the filtering & sorting.

**Laravel controller**

```
// Table1 has 200,000 rows, the query itself is also slow
$rs = DB::select("select *
from Table1");
$numrow = count($rs);

if ($numrow > 0) {
    foreach ($rs as $row) {
        $column1 = $row_customers->column1;
        
        $arr['col1'] = $column1;

        $arrs[] = $arr;
    }
}

$response = Datatables::of($arrs)->make(true)->getData(true);

return response()->json($response);
```

**Laravel view**

```
$('#Table1').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    responsive: true,
    cache: false,
    ajax: {
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        "url": "/GetTable1",
        "type": "POST",
        error: function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log('error.jqXHR', jqXHR);
            console.log('error.ajaxOptions', ajaxOptions);
            console.log('error.thrownError', thrownError);
        }
    }
    /* ... */
});
```

Comment: Best approach is to use pagination, don;t query all the rows instead show records by chunks like a lazy load or something

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Datatables::of()`, try `Datatables::eloquent()` instead, this can make your query faster especially during sorting and filtering as it actually include it in the SQL statement during query instead of filtering it after getting all results.

You can refer more on https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/engine-eloquent#facade